# Extracting a sub file from a zip file

Tags: android, unzip, zip

I have a number of image files in a zip file (more than 50,000). How can I get a file through its name in a zip file without extracting the whole zip?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974798/unzip-file-from-zip-archive-of-multiple-files-on-android-using-zipfile-class?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for to do this programmatically or manually ?

If you want to do it programaticaly you can use the [ZipInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) and iterate over your files and exact only the ones you want.

Take a look at the following post for some examples.

[How to unzip files programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382996/how-to-unzip-files-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Root explorer allows you to open the .zip file without extracting it then just go through it and find the image you want click and hold on it and click extract!